# Is mixture of ammonium hydroxide and ammonium nitrate a buffer solution?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions, buffer

Is a mixture of $\ce{NH4OH}$ and $\ce{NH4NO3}$ a buffer solution?

I have seen some examples with $\ce{NH4OH}$ and $\ce{NH4Cl}$ but never $\ce{NH4NO3}$.

Comment: There should be no difference. Both are salts of strong acids, so...

Comment: NH4OH does not exist as a molecule in water. There is NH3(aq), reacting with water $\ce{NH3(aq) + H2O <<=> NH4+(aq) + OH-(aq)}$. In extreme conditions, like in interstellar space, it may exist as a donor-acceptor pair NH3.H2O

Answer (score 3):

A buffer is a mixture of a weak acid with the conjugate weak base.

> Is a mixture of $\ce{NH4OH}$ and $\ce{NH4NO3}$ a buffer solution? I have seen some examples with $\ce{NH4OH}$ and $\ce{NH4Cl}$ but never $\ce{NH4NO3}$.

Both mixtures contain $\ce{NH4+}$, a weak acid. Where is the conjugate weak base? You can either write $\ce{NH4OH}$ more conventionally (or in a more modern way) as ammonia in aqueous solution, $\ce{NH3(aq)}$, which is a weak base. Or you can recognize $\ce{OH-}$ in ammonium hydroxide as a strong base, which would react with the ammonium to make ammonia. In either way of looking at things, the conjugate base is present as well.

So it is a buffer.